# $grouping in dynamicKey: value format in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Hello everyone I want to group mongodb query results as;

```
var obj = {dynamicKey: value}
```

For example collection is like;

```
{name: "alex" , age: 21},
{name: "felix" , age: 81},
{name: "hannah" , age: 12}, 
{name: "tom" , age: 18}
```

I want to get the collection as;

```
{alex: 21},
{felix: 81},
{hannah: 12}, 
{tom: 18}
```

Is it possible to do this with `$group` in `mongodb`?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group : {
            _id: "",
            "$name" : { $first: "$age"}
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

But this throws an error as; `"errmsg" : "The field name '$name' cannot be an operator name",`

How can I do this?

Comment: Short answer: no, you can't.

Comment: @chridam thank you

Comment: You could however use `mapReduce` to map the result to hashed keys

Comment: What kind of data structure is your expected response ?

Comment: @SatishGarg in JSON format.